# Daily leaderboard or price tracking data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'll just start from scratch since I feel like I'm lost with all the different possibilities. What I will be talking about is leaderboard but could apply to price tracking as well.

My goal is to scrape data from a [website](https://community.koodomobile.com/) (the all time leaderboard / hidden), put it in a .csv file and update it daily at noon.

What I have succeeded so far : scraping the data.

1. Tried scraping [with BS4](https://pastebin.pl/view/4ccc66c0) but since the data is hidden, I couldn't be specific enough to only get the all-time points. I find it's a success because I'm able to get a table with all the data I need and the date as a header. My problem with this solution is 1) unuseful data populating the csv 2) table is vertical and not horizontal
2. Scraped data [with CSS selector](https://pastebin.pl/view/08c4e3b3) but I have abandoned this idea because soemtimes the page won't load and the data wasn't scraped. Found out that there's a json file containing the data right away
3. Json scraping seems to be the best option, but having trouble creating a csv file that's OK to make a graph with.

This is what brings me to what I'm struggling with : storing the data in a table that looks like this where the grey area is the points and the DATE1 is the moment the data has been scraped :
[image: Grey area = points]

I'd like not to manipulate the data in the csv file too much. If the table would look like what I picture above, then it's gonna be easier to make a graph afterwards but I'm having trouble. The best I did is creating a table that looks like this AND that's vertical and not horizontal.

```
name,points,date
Dennis,52570,10-23-2020
Dinh,40930,10-23-2020
name,points,date
Dennis,52570,10-23-2020
Dinh,40930,10-23-2020
name,points,date
Dennis,52570,10-23-2020
Dinh,40930,10-23-2020
```

Thank you for your help.

Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
url_all_time = 'https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?period=allTime&maxResults=20&excludeRoles='
data = pd.read_json(url_all_time)
table = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index=['name'], columns=['points','name'])
table['date'] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
table.to_csv('products.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

If what I want is not possible, I might just scrape individually for each member, make one CSV file per member and make a graph that refers to those different files.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a lightweight database (e.g.SQLite) for easy update, retrieval and query in the future. The target table should be as simple as something like (date, rank, user, score).

Comment: Can you webscrape with this?

Comment: Web scraping (data retrieval), data preprocessing and data storage are three separate steps. If I understand correctly, your question is about data preprocessing and perhaps storage. I assume you are going to deal with the scraping part independently (the `pd.read_json` part already worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've played around with your question a bit and here's what I came up with.

Basically, your best bet for data storage is a light weight database, as suggested in the comments. However, with a bit of planning, a few hoops to jump, and some hacky code you could get away with a simple (sort of) `JSON` that eventually ends up as a `.csv` file that looks like this:

**Note**: *the values are the same as I don't want to wait a day or two for the leader-board to actually update*.

[image]

What I did was rearranging the data that came back from the request to the API and built a structure that looks like this:

```
    "BobTheElectrician": {
        "id": 7160010,
        "rank": 14,
        "score_data": {
            "2020-10-24 18:45": 4187,
            "2020-10-24 18:57": 4187,
            "2020-10-24 19:06": 4187,
            "2020-10-24 19:13": 4187
        }
```

Every player is your main key that has, among others, a `scores_data` value. This in turn is a `dict` that holds `points` value for each day you run the script.

Now, the trick is to get this `JSON` to look like the `.csv` you want. The question is - how?

- Well, since you intend to update all players' data (I just assumed that) they all should have the same number of entries for `score_data`.
- The keys for `score_data` are your timestamps. Grab any player's `score_data` keys and you have the date headers, right?
- Having said that, you can build your `.csv` rows the same way: grab player's name and all their point values from `score_data`. This should get you a list of lists, right? Right.

Then, when you have all this, you just dump that to a `.csv` file and there you have it!

Putting it all together:

```
import csv
import json
import os
import random
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests


API_URL = "https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?"
LEADERBOARD_FILE = "leaderboard_data.json"


def get_leaderboard(period: str = "allTime", max_results: int = 20) -> list:
    payload = {"period": period, "maxResults": max_results}
    return requests.get(f"{API_URL}{urlencode(payload)}").json()


def dump_leaderboard_data(leaderboard_data: dict) -> None:
    with open("leaderboard_data.json", "w") as jf:
        json.dump(leaderboard_data, jf, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


def read_leaderboard_data(data_file: str) -> dict:
    with open(data_file) as f:
        return json.load(f)


def parse_leaderboard(leaderboard: list) -> dict:
    return {
        item["name"]: {
            "id": item["id"],
            "score_data": {
                time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"): item["points"],
            },
            "rank": item["leaderboardPosition"],
        } for item in leaderboard
    }


def update_leaderboard_data(target: dict, new_data: dict) -> dict:
    for player, stats in new_data.items():
        target[player]["rank"] = stats["rank"]
        target[player]["score_data"].update(stats["score_data"])
    return target


def leaderboard_to_csv(leaderboard: dict) -> None:
    data_rows = [
        [player] + list(stats["score_data"].values()) 
        for player, stats in leaderboard.items()
    ]
    random_player = random.choice(list(leaderboard.keys()))
    dates = list(leaderboard[random_player]["score_data"])
    with open("the_data.csv", "w") as output:
        w = csv.writer(output)
        w.writerow([""] + dates)
        w.writerows(data_rows)


def script_runner():
    if os.path.isfile(LEADERBOARD_FILE):
        fresh_data = update_leaderboard_data(
            target=read_leaderboard_data(LEADERBOARD_FILE),
            new_data=parse_leaderboard(get_leaderboard()),
        )
        leaderboard_to_csv(fresh_data)
        dump_leaderboard_data(fresh_data)
    else:
        dump_leaderboard_data(parse_leaderboard(get_leaderboard()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    script_runner()
```

The script also checks if you have a `JSON` file that pretends to be a proper database. If not, it'll write the leader-board data. Next time you run the script, it'll update the `JSON` and spit out a fresh `.csv` file.

Hope this answer will nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think it was possible to rearrange the data that came from the json. Definitely didn't have the knowledge to come up with this. I ended up doing a JSON file for every username and then combine those files in another excel by hand. This solution is definitely better. Will it update id say somebody gets more points then another? or data will be written at same spot eveytime?

Comment: This updates only the score and the rank, but you can easily adapt this to write any data. If you find my answer useful please up-vote and/or accept it.

Comment: Was able to successfully make it work in a cronjob until now. Whenever the script is run in cron, it gives a KeyError but works fine in PyCharm. I'm confused. I didn't change anything.

Comment: I can't help you without an error traceback. Post the issue as a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

Hey since you are loading it in a panda frame it makes the operations fairly simple. I ran your code first

```
 import pandas as pd
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
url_all_time = 'https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?period=allTime&maxResults=20&excludeRoles='
data = pd.read_json(url_all_time)
table = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index=['name'], columns=['points','name'])
table['date'] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Then I added a few more lines of code to modify the panda frame table to your need.

```
idxs = table['date'].index
for i,val in enumerate(idxs):
    table.at[ val , table['date'][i] ] = table['points'][i]
table = table.drop([ 'date', 'points' ], axis = 1)
```

In the above snippet I am using pandas frames ability to assign values using indexes. So first I get index values for the date column then I go through each of them to add column for the required date(values from date column) and get the corresponding points according to the indexes we pulled earlier

This gives me the following output:

```
name    10-24-2020
Dennis  52570.0
Dinh    40930.0
Sophia  26053.0
Mayumi  25300.0
Goran   24689.0
Robert T    19843.0
Allan M 19768.0
Bernard Koodo   14404.0
nim4165 13629.0
Timo Tuokkola   11216.0
rikkster    7338.0
David AKU   5774.0
Ranjan Koodo    4506.0
BobTheElectrician   4170.0
Helen Koodo 3370.0
Mihaela Koodo   2764.0
Fred C  2542.0
Philosoraptor   2122.0
Paul Deschamps  1973.0
Emilia Koodo    1755.0
```

I can then save this to csv using last line from your code. Similar you can pull data for more dates and format it to add it to the same panda frame

```
table.to_csv('products.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to add more data. If I run the script, the data from the last run is being overwritten

Comment: You will have do pandaframename.append(newdataframe). You might be overriding the same variable each time, hence loosing the old data pulled. Flush data to the csv at the end of the code, build the entire required panda frame first.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to say